# Does EF caches entities between different instances of DbContext?

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

Does creating DbContext per query in Asp.net make EF only read the data from its cache, or does it query DB for the whole sets every time? I know about metadata caching per AppDomain, but what about just the data?

Context: data acquisition and visualisation application with MVC4 + Web API frontend, wouldn't call that "high volume", but lots of queries return the same sets of data in some shorter time frame.

Comment: I don't think so that data is cached in entities it is always query DB

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't have a data cache per AppDomain, only a cache per context instance.

If you create a new context per request or query you start with an empty cache and EF will fetch the data from the database.

Moreover, the term "cache per context instance" can be misleading as it doesn't mean that EF won't run queries to the database if the entities are already loaded in the context cache. The way how this cache works and how you can leverage it (or not) is the following:

- **Every** LINQ-to-Entities query on a `DbSet<T>` or generally on an `IQueryable<T>` will run a database query, no matter if the entities already exist in the context or not. But if an entity with the same key as a queried entity already exists in the context EF will throw the result of that query away and return the cached entity instance back to the caller.

  It does this check if the entity with the same key exists **after** it has run the query. (For complex queries - for example queries that contain an `Include` - it can't do this check before because it cannot know which entities and key values will be returned.)

  That's the default behaviour (`MergeOption` is `AppendOnly`). You can change this behaviour to `OverwriteChanges` and other options, I believe, but none of them will avoid that LINQ queries always issue database queries.
- For querying an entity just by its key you can use `GetObjectByKey` or `Find` (with `DbContext`) which will check first if the entity with that key is already cached in the context and then return this cached object. If not it will run a database query to load it.
- You can query EF's ChangeTracker, it's especially well supported with `DbContext` where you have access to the context cache via the `DbSet<T>.Local` collection.

  The problem here is that there is no logic to query the database automatically if a query on `Local` does not return a result. You have to write this logic manually. The even bigger problem is that a query on `Local` is LINQ-to-Objects and not LINQ-to-Entities (`Local` doesn't implement `IQueryable<T>`, only `IEnumerable<T>`), so you often have to rewrite your queries to act on `Local` - for example you can't use `Include` here, your can't use any `EntityFunctions`, you will get different behaviour for string comparisons regarding case sensitivity, etc., etc.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. So far, I had completely missed the fact that cached version may be used, even if queries are issued against the database. I used SQL Server Profiler and saw queries that didn't return fresh data in my application!? I finally found out that my custom MembershipProvider was persisted by the framework between request and so was the context instance it kept. Other code was running in contexts and things got completely messed up.